# How to get views field data in defineOptions() method of custom filter?

Tags: 8, views

I am  creating a custom filter for views. In *.views.inc file I am using `hook_views_data_alter()` to create the filter in views. Then creating a class for filter that extends `NumericFilter` filter class. Now, in `defineOptions()` method I want to feed the min and max numbers. These min and max data comes from a field in the view. Therefore, I want to know how can I get field data in that `defineOptions()` method.

```
class ItemQuantity extends NumericFilter {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function init(ViewExecutable $view, DisplayPluginBase $display, array &$options = NULL) {
    parent::init($view, $display, $options);
    $this->definition['options callback'] = array($this, 'generateOptions');
  }

  protected function defineOptions() {
    $options = parent::defineOptions();

    $options['value'] = [
      'contains' => [
        'min' => ['default' => ''],
        'max' => ['default' => ''],
        'value' => ['default' => ''],
      ],
    ];

    return $options;
  }

  public function operators() {
    $operators = parent::operators();
    $operators['overlaps'] = [
      'title' => $this->t('Overlaps by'),
      'method' => 'opOverlap',
      'short' => $this->t('<>'),
      'values' => 1,
    ];
    return $operators;
  }

  protected function opOverlap($field) {
    $this->query->addWhere($this->options['group'], $field, [$this->value['min'], $this->value['max']], 'IN');
  }

  /**
   * Override the query so that no filtering takes place if the user doesn't
   * select any options.
   */
  public function query() {
    if (!empty($this->value)) {
      parent::query();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Skip validation if no options have been chosen so we can use it as a
   * non-filter.
   */
  public function validate() {
    if (!empty($this->value)) {
      parent::validate();
    }
  }

}
```

I want to get the value of min_quantity field in the view.

Comment: some advance with the problem?

Comment: Yes, but now I am getting another error. "The configuration property display.default.display_options.filters.quantity_filter.value.min doesn't exist." . I am working to resolve this error, once this filter starts working, I'll post the solution so that others might get help :)

Comment: I think that you should open another question because this question *How to get views field data in defineOptions() method of custom filter?* is answered with my answer, and now you have a different problem, that seems to be related with a config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access with:

```
$this->options['value']
```

Read more about this in [Building Views Query Plugins for Drupal 8, Part 3](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/building-views-query-plugins-for-drupal-8-part-3)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but $this->options is giving me a blank array.

Comment: @sorabh.v6 can you add more code to the question? Remember that you need to implement the buildOptionsForm() method.